# How to access request headers in grpc service proxied by. grpc-gateway in golang

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-gateway

I have a grpc server proxied by grpc-gateway. When I make a HTTP call to the gateway endpoint, my corresponding grpc service method is called. Now, the grpc service implementation receives a Context which has the headers. I couldn't figure out how to access the headers.

[image]

When I debug my grpc service and put a breakpoint, this is the structure of the Context object which my service receives. Now, how can I get the value of any of the HTTP request headers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HTTP headers are stored in metadata.

`md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)` should work for getting the incoming metadata.